# CodeIgniter automatically display modal if set_flashdata is not empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need your help. I have an edit form where after successfully edited the records, it will redirect to another page and display automatically the modal with the message passed from set_flashdata.

This is what I've tried so far:

**View**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSuccess">
                                        Modal Success
                                    </button>

                                    <div class="modal fade modal-success" id="modalSuccess" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Success</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <?php echo $message;?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">OK</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
 // check to see if we are updating the user
            if($this->ion_auth->update($user->id, $data))
            {
                // redirect them back to the admin page if admin, or to the base url if non admin
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages() );
                if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin())
                {
                    redirect('auth/profile/', 'refresh');
                }
                else
                {
                    redirect('auth/profile/, 'refresh');
                }

            }
```

I have no idea how to fire modal automatically once it receives message from set_flashdata. Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter session set flash data only works when you have it redirecting.

Currently you have set the flash data out side of the redirect

And because you are using refresh with redirect it it will clear it .

```
if($this->ion_auth->update($user->id, $data)) {

// redirect them back to the admin page if admin, or to the base url if non admin


if ($this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {

    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
    redirect('auth/profile');

} else {

    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
    redirect('auth/profile');
}


}
```

On view to echo flashdata

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view file you should put:

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('message')):?>
<script>
    $('#modalSuccess').modal('show');
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Make sure you have `jQuery.js` and `bootstrap.js` loaded before.